# Generating schedule for pair game

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

We have 8 players.

On one table plays 4 players (two pairs).

[image]

So every player need to be pair with all other 7 players and to have that players as opponent same count.

In case of just creating tables with deleting it from list we have:

```
Tour 1: (1,2) - (3,4) | (5,6) - (7,8)
Tour 2: (1,3) - (2,5) | (4,7) - (6,8)
.....................................
.....................................
Tour 7: (1,8) - (2,7) | (3,6) - (4,5)
```

But some payers will have some opponents often than others.

In that direction I need to think?

****UPDATE****
In case of Jens Schauders solution we'll have 7 rounds. And if chack opponents for player 2 we will have 3 times opponent 4 and just one time opponent 7.

If split pair in this schema

```
       TABLE 1 |  TABLE 2

Pair1: 1    2  |  3    4
      ------------------
Pair2: 5    6  |  7    8
```

Where is mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is an easy visualization for the algorithm you are looking for:

Imagine a long table with opponents sitting opposite of each other:

```
1    2    3    4
----------------
5    6    7    8
```

Now for each new round everybody moves to the place left of him. Possibly to the other side of the table, with one exception: Player one keeps her seat. So the next round would look like this

```
1    5    2    3    
----------------
6    7    8    4
```

If you now split the long table in two part you get suitable pairings for your small tables.

**Regarding the updated question**

To achieve a more evenly distributed opponents one could try to split the large table differently, e.g building a small table from first and fourth column, and the second small table from column 2+3

Comment: There are little problem. Could you please the question update?

Comment: I tried all variants (even in diagonal), but at least one opponent appear 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 6 unique games between 4 teams. There are 7 possible pairing hence 42 unique games.

Each player pairs up with every other player only once and play against each one of them 6 times exactly.

List:

```
Pairs 01: (1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)
PairRound 1:
GameRound 01: (1,2) - (3,4) | (5,6) - (7,8)
GameRound 02: (1,2) - (7,8) | (3,4) - (5,6)
GameRound 03: (1,2) - (5,6) | (3,4) - (7,8)

Pairs 02: (1,3),(2,4),(5,7),(6,8)
PairRound 2:
GameRound 04: (1,3) - (2,4) | (5,7) - (6,8)
GameRound 05: (1,3) - (6,8) | (2,4) - (5,7)
GameRound 06: (1,3) - (5,7) | (2,4) - (6,8)

Pairs 03: (1,4),(2,3),(5,8),(6,7)
PairRound 3:
GameRound 07: (1,4) - (2,3) | (6,7) - (5,8)
GameRound 08: (1,4) - (5,8) | (2,3) - (6,7)
GameRound 09: (1,4) - (6,7) | (2,3) - (5,8)

Pairs 04: (1,5),(2,6),(3,7),(4,8)
PairRound 4:
GameRound 10: (1,5) - (2,6) | (3,7) - (4,8)
GameRound 11: (1,5) - (4,8) | (2,6) - (3,7)
GameRound 12: (1,5) - (3,7) | (2,6) - (4,8)

Pairs 05: (1,6),(2,5),(3,8),(4,7)
PairRound 5:
GameRound 13: (1,6) - (2,5) | (3,8) - (4,7)
GameRound 14: (1,6) - (4,7) | (2,5) - (3,8)
GameRound 15: (1,6) - (3,8) | (2,5) - (4,7)

Pairs 06: (1,7),(2,8),(3,5),(4,6)
PairRound 6:
GameRound 16: (1,7) - (2,8) | (3,5) - (4,6)
GameRound 17: (1,7) - (4,6) | (2,8) - (3,5)
GameRound 18: (1,7) - (3,5) | (2,8) - (4,6)

Pairs 07: (1,8),(2,7),(3,6),(4,5)
PairRound 8:
GameRound 19: (1,8) - (2,7) | (3,6) - (4,5)
GameRound 20: (1,8) - (4,5) | (2,7) - (3,6)
GameRound 21: (1,8) - (3,6) | (2,7) - (4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are two schedules. The 1st schedule is a 2 round robin fixed partners schedule.  It is a balanced 2 round robin "pairs" schedule. Or, another way of putting it is we are scheduling 'pairs' of 'pairs'.  I think it's what you are looking for?

The 2nd schedule is a "balanced" 2 round robin 'singles' schedule for 8 players (each player is a team).

**Note: On both schedules, all players/teams rotate through the all the tables.** There is no player/team fixed in a set location **which is undesirable for most leagues because it creates unbalanced time slot distribution**. The other two answers posted on this thread locks in a single team in a single time slot then rotates the other 7 teams through that time slot.

The PAIRS-4 schedule below is a **fixed partner** schedule. We also have an 8 player **rotating partners** schedule. In each round robin all players are partnered with each of the other 7 players once, and play against all the other players exactly twice.

```
PAIRS-4 SCHEDULE                     Date 8/4/14            
-    
DATE   DAY  TIME   LOCATION     GM#   HOME  v  AWAY
Week 1         
AUG  4 MON  6:00pm Table-1       1  #1 & #2 v #7 & #8
AUG  4 MON  6:00pm Table-2       1  #3 & #4 v #5 & #6
Week 2
AUG 11 MON  6:00pm Table-1       2  #7 & #8 v #3 & #4
AUG 11 MON  6:00pm Table-2       2  #5 & #6 v #1 & #2
Week 3    
AUG 18 MON  6:00pm Table-1       3  #1 & #2 v #3 & #4
AUG 18 MON  6:00pm Table-2       3  #5 & #6 v #7 & #8
Week 4
AUG 25 MON  6:00pm Table-1       4  #5 & #6 v #3 & #4
AUG 25 MON  6:00pm Table-2       4  #7 & #8 v #1 & #2
Week 5        
SEP  1 MON  6:00pm Table-1       5  #1 & #2 v #5 & #6
SEP  1 MON  6:00pm Table-2       5  #3 & #4 v #7 & #8
Week 6    
SEP  8 MON  6:00pm Table-1       6  #7 & #8 v #5 & #6
SEP  8 MON  6:00pm Table-2       6  #3 & #4 v #1 & #2
-    
========================================================
-
SINGLES-8 SCHEDULE               Date 8/5/14 
-
DATE   DAY  TIME    LOCATION   GM#  HOME v AWAY
Week 1
AUG  5 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1     1   #1 v #8
AUG  5 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2     1   #2 v #7
AUG  5 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3     1   #3 v #6
AUG  5 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4     1   #4 v #5
Week 2    
AUG 12 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1     2   #5 v #2
AUG 12 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2     2   #8 v #6
AUG 12 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3     2   #7 v #1
AUG 12 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4     2   #3 v #4
Week 3
AUG 19 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1     3   #2 v #3
AUG 19 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2     3   #5 v #7
AUG 19 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3     3   #4 v #8
AUG 19 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4     3   #6 v #1
Week 4
AUG 26 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1     4   #6 v #4
AUG 26 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2     4   #1 v #5
AUG 26 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3     4   #7 v #3
AUG 26 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4     4   #8 v #2
Week 5
SEP  2 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1     5   #3 v #5
SEP  2 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2     5   #4 v #1
SEP  2 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3     5   #2 v #6
SEP  2 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4     5   #7 v #8
Week 6
SEP  9 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1     6   #6 v #7
SEP  9 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2     6   #4 v #2
SEP  9 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3     6   #5 v #8
SEP  9 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4     6   #1 v #3
Week 7
SEP 16 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1     7   #7 v #4
SEP 16 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2     7   #8 v #3
SEP 16 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3     7   #2 v #1
SEP 16 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4     7   #5 v #6
Week 8
SEP 23 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1     8   #7 v #2
SEP 23 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2     8   #6 v #3
SEP 23 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3     8   #5 v #4
SEP 23 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4     8   #8 v #1
Week 9
SEP 30 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1     9   #6 v #8
SEP 30 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2     9   #1 v #7
SEP 30 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3     9   #4 v #3
SEP 30 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4     9   #2 v #5
Week 10
OCT  7 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1    10   #7 v #5
OCT  7 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2    10   #8 v #4
OCT  7 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3    10   #1 v #6
OCT  7 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4    10   #3 v #2
Week 11
OCT 14 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1    11   #5 v #1
OCT 14 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2    11   #3 v #7
OCT 14 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3    11   #2 v #8
OCT 14 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4    11   #4 v #6
Week 12
OCT 21 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1    12   #1 v #4
OCT 21 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2    12   #6 v #2
OCT 21 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3    12   #8 v #7
OCT 21 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4    12   #5 v #3
Week 13
OCT 28 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1    13   #2 v #4
OCT 28 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2    13   #8 v #5
OCT 28 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3    13   #3 v #1
OCT 28 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4    13   #7 v #6
Week 14
NOV  4 TUE  6:00pm  Table-1    14   #3 v #8
NOV  4 TUE  6:00pm  Table-2    14   #1 v #2
NOV  4 TUE  6:00pm  Table-3    14   #6 v #5
NOV  4 TUE  6:00pm  Table-4    14   #4 v #7
-               
-                 # # # # #    
-
```

You can copy & paste the schedules above into your word processor and use
Search & Replace to replace the player numbers with real names.  You can also
edit the schedule, ie, change dates & times, add notes, graphics, contact 
info for each player, etc.

Comment: There's no need to include your signature in the post as it's automatically attached to the bottom of the post.